# Custom Launcher is not remaining as default launcher in Huawei device

Tags: android, android-launcher, huawei-mobile-services

I have developed a custom launcher/homescreen and it has been working perfectly on all android version for nearly two years. So far this launcher has been used in various Samsung devices.

Currently I am testing it in new huawei lua-u22 device. My launcher runs, can be set as default and shows up other apps on top of launcher too. But if I run another app (for example Gmail), screen lock(Swipe only) for 20-30 second, unlock device then press back button then instead of bringing it back to my launcher it goes back to default huawei homescreen. I checked by going to the settings-> home and there my launcher was still set as default. It only brings back my launcher home screen when I press home button again.

Is this problem of huawei device that is always redrawing default huwaei home as homescreen? Is there anyway I can track default selected home change at any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the reason. In huawei after screen is tuned off my app was getting killed.

Huawei has a feature *Protected Apps* which allows application that is enabled in the list to keep running when screen is turned off. After I allowed my app in Protected apps it was not getting killed after screen turned off and everything now working properly.

To enable this feature go to **System settings** (which you can either find in the quick toggles portion of the notification shade by pulling down the status bar on the top portion of the screen). Go to **All** tab, Scroll down to **Privacy and Security section**, go to to **Protected Apps** and enable your app(this will control what’s allowed to run when the screen is off and what isn’t)

In stackoverflow there are few codes available to run this screen pro-grammatically which I do not find reliable enough as it may change in any new version of device.